# Angular 5 Error submitting form programmatically

Tags: angular

In my angular 5 application I need to submit a form programmatically with hidden fields, my 3 fields are binded to variables.

```
<form #testForm name="form1" action="paymentUrl" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" [(ngModel)]="paymentUrl">
    <input type="hidden" name="xml" [(ngModel)]="paymentXml">
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" [(ngModel)]="paymentHash">
</form>
```

In .ts I have:

```
 @ViewChild('testForm') testFormEl: any;

this.testFormEl.nativeElement.submit()
```

But when I try to submit the form in the request I see:
[image]
like if the fields are not correctly added to the form, 
how can I fix it?

Comment: No one will ever be able to enter anything in a hidden field. So why use bidirectional binding? Why not just use `<input type="hidden" name="url" [value]="paymentUrl">`?

Comment: @JBNizet Ok I follow your way, but I am not sending anything

Comment: And if I use a type="text" and I write something inside fields the form submitting these value